# In sql server I want to get class name ,student name who score maximum mark along with their Maximum mark.Table details given below

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a **StudentDetails** table as below

```
select * from StudentDetails
```

[image]

And we have **Class** table as below

```
select * from Class
```

[image]

I know by using **group by**  and **aggregate** function we can display easily maximum marks obtained in each class by below query

```
select C.Name as 'ClassName',
       MAX(SD.Mark) as 'Max Mark' 
from   StudentDetails SD 
       inner join Class C on SD.classid = C.ClassId group by C.Name
```

giving below result

[image]

But now I need to display the student name also along with the maximum mark in each class by using **group by** and **aggregate function**. I used below query but it did not give expected result.

```
select C.Name as 'ClassName',
       SD.Name as 'Student Name', 
       Max(SD.Mark) as 'Max Mark' 
from   StudentDetails SD 
       inner join Class C on SD.classid = C.ClassId 
group by C.Name,SD.Name
```

giving below result .

[image]

This result is not as expected, I need a query which will result

```
Division A , Mrx , 536
Division B , MrC , 535.
```

using **group by** and **aggregate** function Please somebody help me..

Comment: you have found the maximum marks by class, so just to do a join back to `StudentDetails` table to get the student name. You will need to use `CTE` or `derived table` or `sub-query`

Comment: Erm, is `studentid` unique in `studentdetails`? If so, a student can only attend one class, which doesn't seem to make sense. If not so, a student can be named John in class 1 and Jane in class 2, which doesn't seem to make sense either.

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals by the way. For names it's double quotes in standard SQL and brackets in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a derived table.  The derived table takes the ClassID with it's MAX(Mark).  The receiving query and joins apply the appropriate descriptions.

```
SELECT C.Name
      ,SD.Name
      ,dT.MaxMark
  FROM ( 
         --Gets the MaxMark per ClassID
         SELECT S.ClassID
               ,MAX(Mark) [MaxMark]
           FROM StudentDetails S
         GROUP BY S.ClassID  
       ) AS dT INNER JOIN StudentDetails SD ON SD.Mark = dT.MaxMark
               INNER JOIN Class C ON C.ClassID = dT.ClassID
```

Gives output:

```
Name        Name    MaxMark
Division A  MrX     536
Division B  MrC     535
```

If you want to examine the full code: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00635/10/0)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
WITH CTE AS(

     select C.Name as 'ClassName',
            MAX(SD.Mark) as 'Max Mark' 
     from   StudentDetails SD 
            inner join Class C on SD.classid = C.ClassId group by C.Name
)
SELECT STudentName,*
FROM CTE
INNER JOIN StudentDetails SD ON Marks = [Max Marks]
```

Comment: You have a mismatch here: `'Max Mark'` vs. `[Max Marks]`. Moreover your query is incomplete, because marks should be related to a class. So include the `classid` in your CTE and your `ON` clause.

Comment: Thanks Jaydip Jadhav.  You are correct with small syntactical issues in your query. Please find below correction "WITH CTE AS(

     select C.Name as 'ClassName',
            MAX(SD.Mark) as 'Max Mark' 
     from   StudentDetails SD 
            inner join Class C on SD.classid = C.ClassId group by C.Name
)
SELECT SD.Name,CTE.ClassName,CTE.[MAX MARK]
FROM CTE
INNER JOIN StudentDetails SD ON SD.Mark = CTE.[Max Mark] "

Comment: Well! That was Typo ;p

Answer (score 0):

You want to compare a student class result with the maximum class result. The easiest way to do this is with `MAX OVER`:

```
select classname, studentname, mark
from
(
  select
    c.name as classname,
    sd.name as studentname,
    sd.mark,
    max(sd.mark) over (partition by sd.class) as class_max_mark
  from studentdetails s
  join class c on c.classid = sd.classid
) analysed
where mark = class_max_mark;
```

If you are forced to use `GROUP BY`, then you'd want:

```
select
  c.name as classname,
  sd.name as studentname,
  sd.mark
from studentdetails s
join class c on c.classid = sd.classid
where (sd.classid, sd.mark) in
(
  select classid, max(mark)
  from studentdetails
  group by classid
);
```

SQL Server, however, doesn't support `IN` clauses with multiple columns. So you need a join which obfuscates the query slightly:

```
select
  c.name as classname,
  sd.name as studentname,
  sd.mark
from studentdetails s
join class c on c.classid = sd.classid
join
(
  select classid, max(mark) as max_mark
  from studentdetails
  group by classid
) m on m.classid = sd.classid and m.max_mark = sd.mark;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of dense_rank

```
select StudName, ClsName, Mark from 
  (
      select Dense_Rank() over(partition by #Table_studentDetails.classId 
       order by Mark desc) Rank, 
      #Table_studentDetails.Name StudName, #Table_Class.Name ClsName,Mark
      from #Table_studentDetails inner join #Table_Class on 
      #Table_studentDetails.classid = #Table_Class.classid

    )T
 where Rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a correlated subquery in `WHERE`

```
select C.Name as 'ClassName',
       SD.name,
       SD.Mark as 'Max Mark' 
from   StudentDetails SD 
inner join Class C on SD.classid = C.ClassId
where sd.mark = (select max(mark) from StudentDetails s where sd.classid = s.classid)
```

Comment: Why the downvote? And why doing this without leaving a comment at that? This solution looks okay to me.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner this is simply SO :)

Comment: It works ok, but I had needed something using group by

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select B.Name, A.Name, A.Mark from (
    select Name, Mark, ClassId, MAX() over (partition by ClassId) as MaxMark from StudentDetails
) as A join Class as C on A.ClassId = C.ClassId
where A.Mark = A.MaxMark
```